# Can't add a style to my CSS document

Tags: css, asp.net

guys, thanks before anything. Well, I have a reaaaaaaally wierd problem here. I am working in an ASP.NET application (VS 2012) and of course I'm using CSS to style my pages. I stop working yesterday night, all was great, and now when I am here I discover that any style I add to my CSS file does not apply. The funny part is that (trying to figure out if was a problem with the style) I have put it in another separated file (ugly solution) and it works! I beleive it is not a CSS error either, because I have moved my new style all around the CSS document and, no matter where it is, does not apply. It it like if the css does not admit any other rule. Please, someone tell me that has had a similar issue, and how to correct this. It would be really disturbing if I had to do a different CSS file each day to have all my styles running and showing correctly. Hope someone has any ideas, thanks again...

Comment: Press F12 and check in the network while your application is running, which css file is loading and the path.I think you can find the root cause.

Comment: Clear your cache to make sure that isn't factoring in...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser will cache the old style sheet. If you are adding a new style sheet can add a query string to force the new style sheet to be used.

Each time I deploy a new style sheet with the same name I will use this naming convention and update the version(v=) each time e.g "main.css?v=1". This will force the browser to get the latest style sheet.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you VERY MUCH, Mr Jeremy Kern!!! I didn't know that you could use the version after the css name, but worked, and amazing! Thank you and thank you, very very much...